# Calling Setter of JSF Bean possible if associated component not rendered?

Tags: java, security, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a question concerning the security of JSF. Would it be possible for an attacker to call a setter of a JSF Bean if the associated component is not rendered (for example with a tool like curl)?
Or is this checked by JSF so that I can assume this as secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only attackable if the `rendered` condition depends on data which comes along with the HTTP request like parameters, headers, cookies, etc. The entire HTTP request is namely fully user-controlled.

If you're for example only checking the role of the logged-in user, then it's safe -unless the enduser guesses the right username/password of an user with the desired role and logs in with it, of course.